# ST_Within for TIN or 3D objct in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, tin

I would like to query if a point is located in the TIN object. My TIN object is closed (convex hull) object (i.e. surface of a round object). I tried to use `ST_Within`, but the error message returns as:

> ERROR: Unknown geometry type: 15 - Tin

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT ST_Within(mypoint,mytinobject) As mypointinmytinobject
FROM
(SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(x,y,z)', SRID) As mypoint,
(SELECT geom FROM mytintable WHERE gid=1) As mytinobject
) As myobjects;
```

What are the equivalent 3D query functions like `ST_Within` for 3D TIN object in PostGIS?

It is a complex 3D anatomical region. It is not solid, it is a surface. If it is represented as Polyhedralsurface, how could we query if a point is located inside this closed surface (or a region). Do I need to make it solid body. Could it be done in PostGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a TIN for this, use a polyhedral surface, and the ST_3DDistance function to test for containment tests.